# What's the best way to have two Text elements of different sizes line up on the same baseline?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have two text views of different font sizes, and I want them to line up on the same baseline.  I.e:

```
HStack {
    Text("100").font(.largeTitle)
    Text("kg")
}
```

And here I want `100` and `kg` to line up as if they are text on the same line, even though the font sizes are different.

I have tried setting `alignment: .bottom` on the HStack, but obviously this aligns the bottoms of the text views, not the font baseline.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted this one

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {   // << here !!
    Text("100").font(.largeTitle)
    Text("kg")
}
```

[image]